How to fetch the URL in streamlit? when I use oauth2.0 to generate the access token
I have used oauth2.0 implicit flow to authenticate and generate the access token using IAM and internal service provider, I can see the access token generated in the URL but I'm not ale to fetch that because URL has '#' instead of '?', in this case how can I fetch the URL in streamlit?
I have used javascript to fetch the url but not ale to send it to streamlit, could anyone please help me resolve this?
i tried javascript to fetch the url, javascript side is working, I can see the variable i console, but not able to get that to streamlit

OAuth2 implicit flow (which is no longer recommended) is a flow for browser applications. The important information is in the URL in the fragment part (#).
You don't really need to 'fetch' this URL. The assumption is that you get sent to a browser application and using Javascript you extract the data from document.location.
If you're hoping to do stuff on the server instead, implicit flow is the wrong choice. Use the authorization_code flow which is the recommended flow these days for browsers as well.

I need to fetch the url to verify the access token it generated, in streamlit it’s not possible because there is no ‘?’ In the url, Is there any other way to extract the access token ? I’m using streamlit application

Again, you can't 'fetch' this URL. The browser redirects back to your application (which includes the token in the URL) and Javascript extracts the data from the URL. By the time you get the token in the URL it's already open in a browser. There's no fetching anymore at this point.

Oh, then how to verify the token?

You can verify if the token is correct by using it. If it doesn't work, it was incorrect.

What you mean by using it? If I can’t fetch how can I use it? Is there any way to do that in streamlit?

By 'fetching' I mean doing a HTTP request. Not sure about streamlit

This library can extract # URL fragments from current url
https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-url-fragment/
from their documentation,
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_url_fragment import get_fragment

st.write("Current value: {!r}".format(get_fragment()))

